# Why are the parameter types declared outside the parenthesis?

Tags: c, function, coding-style

some times i see that functions are defined as below:

```
read_dir(dir)
char    *dir;   
{
        DIR * dirp;
        struct dirent *d;

        /* open directory */
        dirp = opendir(dir);
  ......... so  on
```

here what is the importance  of the  statement

```
char    *dir;
```

what is the intension behind declaring the pointer soon after the function name and then starting the function body.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's an older C syntax, kalled "[K&R C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#K.26R_C)" since it's how it appeared in the original version of the [legendary book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_%28book%29).

What used to be written like this:

```
foo(a, b)
int a;
int b;
{
}
```

is now

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It is just "old style", [K&R C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K.26R_C) function definition (see [Kernighan & Ritchie's book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_(book)), commonly referred to as simply *Kernighan & Ritchie*.)

The code you refer to may have been written in the late eighties, or early nineties with portability (i.e. compatibility with older compilers, possibly on more "exotic" platforms) in mind.

> Even after the publication of the 1989 C standard, for many years K&R C was still considered the "lowest common denominator" to which C programmers restricted themselves when maximum portability was desired, since many older compilers were still in use, and because carefully written K&R C code can be legal Standard C as well.

Some people *may believe* that K&R-style function definition, still supported by compilers, are more readable, which is in fact not necessarily true; compare:

```
some_function(param1,param2,param3)
char    *param1;   /* param1 comment */
int     param2;    /* param2 comment */
short   param3;    /* param3 comment */
{
}
```

with

```
/* notice also that return type is explicitly specified now */
int
some_function(
  char    *param1, /* param1 comment */
  int     param2,  /* param2 comment */
  short   param3   /* param3 comment */
)   
{
}
```

K&R-style function definitions have been **obsolete since 1989**; see
section 6.9.5 "Function definitions" in the C90 standard.